# Set State to Array Filter value on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So i want to use array.filter to values that are not empty string in an object in the following senario

```
setData(
                _.filter(rows, item => {
                    return (
                        item.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(filterTable.searchByName.toLowerCase()) &&
                        item.email.toLowerCase().includes(filterTable.searchByEmail.toLowerCase()) &&
                        item.cognitoId.toLowerCase().includes(filterTable.searchByCognitoId.toLowerCase()) &&
                        item.mfaEnabled.toString() === filterTable.searchByMfa.toString()
                    );
                })
            );
```

i can use ifelse to what values are there but that will be a hell of a long ifelse

in the above code i want to add those items in _.filter that's value is `!== ''`

for example if `filterTable.email === ''` then i want following

```
setData(
                _.filter(rows, item => {
                    return (
                        item.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(filterTable.searchByName.toLowerCase()) && 
                        item.cognitoId.toLowerCase().includes(filterTable.searchByCognitoId.toLowerCase()) &&
                        item.mfaEnabled.toString() === filterTable.searchByMfa.toString()
                    );
                })
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another `&&` for the search property

Try like this

```
setData(
    _.filter(rows, item => {
        return (
            filterTable?.searchByName &&
            item.firstName
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(filterTable.searchByName.toLowerCase()) &&
            filterTable?.searchByEmail &&
            item.email
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(filterTable.searchByEmail.toLowerCase()) &&
            filterTable?.searchByCognitoId &&
            item.cognitoId
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(filterTable.searchByCognitoId.toLowerCase()) &&
            item.mfaEnabled.toString() === filterTable.searchByMfa.toString()
        );
    })
);
```

Comment: @Ahsan Baloch, check this out !!

Comment: Amila Senadheera no it does not work, ive already tried that. copied ur code too didnt work

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it thanks Amila for helping

```
setData(
            _.filter(rows, item => {
                return (
                    (filterTable?.searchByName !== ''
                        ? item.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(filterTable.searchByName.toLowerCase()) ||
                          item.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(filterTable.searchByName.toLowerCase())
                        : true) &&
                    (filterTable?.searchByEmail !== ''
                        ? item.email.toLowerCase().includes(filterTable.searchByEmail.toLowerCase())
                        : true) &&
                    (filterTable?.searchByCognitoId !== ''
                        ? item.cognitoId.toLowerCase().includes(filterTable.searchByCognitoId.toLowerCase())
                        : true)
                );
            })
        );
```